# Running sbt with Wartremover

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt

I'd like to check the code of my whole project with [wartremover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) and sbt.

I've added `addSbtPlugin("org.brianmckenna" % "sbt-wartremover" % "0.13"` to `plugins.sbt`, but don't know what to do next.

I don't get any output from **wartremover** with `sbt run` and `sbt compile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in [the documentation](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover), you will need to configure the linter:

`wartremoverErrors ++= Warts.unsafe`

With sbt >= 0.13.5 and the auto plugin feature, that's all. I get compilation errors with the examples as soon as I add the line above.